# Blocking input when re-sending get request from raspberry pi to flask app

Tags: python-3.x, windows, flask, raspberry-pi

I am sending a get request from python code in raspberry pi to my flask application, so that in response I can get two parameters from the user- PIN and STATUS.

I am sending the current state of the pins every 10 seconds from raspberry pi with the function `pin_state()`.

The problem I am having is that when I try to send input back to raspberry pi, it keeps asking for input as many times as the number of get requests i have sent with raspberry pi.

So if I have sent 3 requests from raspberry pi to the app, the server will keep asking for PIN input and Status input three times and then send the results back.

Here is the code I am using in raspberry pi and flask app.

```
##Raspberry pi code
    payload=(('mess',pin_state()),("count",count))
    URL=('http://92c648b9.ngrok.io/post1')
    r=requests.get(url=URL,params=payload,timeout=10)
    print r.content
    a=json.loads(r.content)
    pin= int(a["pin"])
    status= int(a["status"])
## flask app code (windows10, visual studio 2017)
@app.route('/post1', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post1():
    message= request.args.get('mess') 
    count = request.args.get('count') 
    print ("Number of times a get request is recieved: %s"%count)
    b=json.loads(message)
    print (b["sensor"])
    print (b["mess1"])
    print (b["mess2"])
    print (b["mess3"])
    print (b["mess4"])
    print (b["mess5"])
    print (b["mess6"])
    print (b["mess7"])
    print (b["mess8"])
    pin = input("PIN: ")
    status=input("Status: ")
    my_dict={"pin":pin, "status": status}
    return json.dumps(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is a typo in your code.

```
statusi=input("Status: ")
```

Is it **status** or **statusi**

Secondly you may try using session

You will need to keep the pin or and status in a session

First you will need to import session from flask. Add this on the top very page

```
from flask import Flask, session
```

Now you can set sessions for pin and status or whatever

```
pin = input("PIN: ")
status=input("Status: ")

session['pin'] = pin
session['status'] = status

my_dict={"pin": session['pin'], "status": session['status']}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The parameter is status, i fixed it in the code. I tried your code, but it stills keeps asking for many inputs until the number of requests made from raspberry pi is reached. I have fixed it using the kbhit from msvcrt module, and if data is entered withing the 10seconds it will be sent, otherwise some null parameters will be send.